# Postgres - Error while adding constraints

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Can anyone tell me what this error is? And How to resolve it?

ERROR:

> could not read block 27651 in file "base/114689/118316": read only
>   4096 of 8192 bytes CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT fk."_ID" FROM ONLY
>   "public"."table1" fk LEFT OUTER JOIN ONLY "public"."table2" pk ON (
>   pk."_ID"::pg_catalog.text OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=)
>   fk."_ID"::pg_catalog.text) WHERE pk."_ID" IS NULL AND (fk."_ID" IS NOT
>   NULL)"

Comment: Read and act on https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption **now**. Hopefully it's just a damaged index, but that should not happen either. Looks like a file is truncated.

Comment: Dear Craig, I am trying to migrate from mysql to postgres using python script.  when i have used "DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED" for index its restored properly with out any error. with the same dump when i tried with "" for index, its showing the above error.

Comment: If you can cause that with only SQL commands then that is probably a bug. If you can provide full step by step instructions and input for causing it then please report it as a bug. Otherwise I will need more detail on the steps taken.

Comment: The following steps i am using to migrate from mysql to postgres. In step 4 DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED is used. Instead of that if i removed those words and keep it empty i am getting the above error. please tell me whether it is mandatory or any other has to be replaced.

Comment: 1. mysqldump --compatible=postgresql --default-character-set=utf8 -r db1.mysql -u root  -p db1       2. python dbconverter.py db1.mysql db1.psql
    3. psql -h localhost -d db1 -U test_user -W -f db1.psql
4. elif line.startswith("CONSTRAINT"): foreign_key_lines.append("ALTER TABLE \"%s\" ADD CONSTRAINT %s DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED" % (current_table, line.split("CONSTRAINT")[1].strip().rstrip(",")